# How do I add separate templates in each sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have a set of templates created for our need , now I create a new workbook , I want to be able to insert a custom template in one sheet and another custom template in another sheet .

Answer (score 0):

To merge two template workbooks together:

Determine which workbook you want to host all of the templates.

Open the first template file that you want to merge with the "host" workbook.

Right click on the worksheet tab.

Select Move or Copy...

Select the workbook you want the template to reside in the To book: drop down field.

Click Ok.

I did this with three installed templates, billing statement, personal monthly budget and expense report. I moved the budget and expense report worksheets into the billing statement workbook without any apparent loss of functionality.

Good Luck.